# Why the curly bracket?

Tags: matrix, output-formatting, formatting

**Why are there the curly braces** in the output of

```
DY = {{Cos[ay], 0, Sin[ay]}, {0, 1, 0}, {-Sin[ay], 0, Cos[ay], 
   0}}; DY // MatrixForm
```

[image: MatrixForm of a matrix with inconsistent curly braces]

It looks inconsistent to a similar example where the display is what I expected: For

```
DX = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[ax], Sin[ax]}, {0, -Sin[ax], 
   Cos[ax]}};   DX // MatrixForm
```

I get

[image: What I expect from MatrixForm]

Would somebody please show some light on this and possibly tell me, how to get rid of the inner curly braces?

Comment: The first example you give for `DY` is not a matrix.  It is a list of three lists, two of which are length 3 and the third is of length 4.  A matrix would be represented as a list of identical length sublists.  Some call this a "ragged matrix".  These are not formatted as a matrix by `MatrixForm`.

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
DY = {{Cos[ay], 0, Sin[ay]}, {0, 1, 0}, {-Sin[ay], 0, Cos[ay]}};
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

**A potential error:**

```
{{Cos[ay], 0, Sin[ay]}, {0, 1, 0}, {-Sin[ay], 0, Cos[ay], 0}};
```

Look at the sub-list no. 3, you've got additional `0` in there making the lists of un-equal lengths;

Comment: Excuse me, I looked at it over aand over but did not get that. You are right!

Comment: By the way: Would it not be possible to issue a warning if MatrixForm is called for something with Lists of Lists, where the lists of the intermediate level(s) do not have equal lenths? - Just a warning, since formally, MatrixForm of "something" is displayed as a column vector of "something" and if that is a list of lists with unequal lenght, then it would look like aboutwhat I falsely complained.

Comment: There is many ways how to do this but for instance, you could do something like this: `If[AllTrue[data, Length @ # == 3 &],
 data // MatrixForm,
 Print["Error! Un-equal sub-list length"]
 ]` , where `data` is your nested lists and `3` is the amount of expected elements in the list;